# Fullcalendar.js get specific day of event on event click

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to get specific day of event on event click?

Example:

I have one event that is through whole week. On `eventClick()` event i get object that has start date and end date. Is it possible to click on specific day of that event and get object that has date of the day i clicked on? Like if i click on event on monday i get the event object back AND date of that monday, and if i click on tuesday i get the same thing but with the date of that tuesday?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible unfortunately. This gets quite a lot on this site. What is your overall goal in wanting to do so? Perhaps there is another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your response. Users can select time span (that can be multiple months long) and set the starting time for event, and that event will be every day at that time. What i need to create is to let them select specific day in that event and change starting time only for that day in that event. I think that next thing to try is to instead creating one big event, i can create event for every day in that time span.

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do. If the event has a specific start and end time each day, then it's not one continuous event (because it doesn't continue over midnight each day, for example), it's a series of separate events. You can set a custom field of some sort if you need a way to relate them to each other (like linking them in a sequence I mean), but yeah if you want to be able to edit the start time of one individual occurrence then you need to declare them as separate events

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. I will try that.